# How to draw widget on available height in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I have a widget that needs to draw on the remaining height where that widget needs to be drawn in between the top and bottom widget(Bottom widget drawn with bottom center attribute).

Ex:

Container() -- The First container almost take half screen

Container() -- The Second container draw on the bottom of the screen eg: Consider widget as Button

Container() -- The Third Container needs to be drawn in between two containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Expanded widget** would work for this scenario where we need to wrap middle widget with it.

Eg:

```
Expanded(
        child: Container(
              ...         
            ),
         ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I know a better method using `MediaQuery.of()`, where you just put the percentage of the space available that a widget will cover:

```
final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
const SizedBox(height: mediaQuery.size.heigh * [percentage of the screen]
```

But this way **includes AppBar space** too. So if you want to exclude it, you should do this:

1. Create appBar variable:

```
    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
          title: const Text('Personal expensense'),
        );
```

2. Subtract mediaQuery.size with appBar variable size:

```
    final availableHeight = mediaQuery.size.height -
            appBar.preferredSize.height -
            mediaQuery.padding.top;
```

**A full example**:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      title: const Text('Personal expensense'),
    );

    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    final availableHeight = mediaQuery.size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        mediaQuery.padding.top;

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: availableHeight * 0.4,
          child: Container(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: availableHeight * 0.3,
          child: Container(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: availableHeight * 0.3,
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It happens to be really useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like a `Column`, you probably want to use the `Expanded` widget.

Try this code

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 100),
    ),
    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100),
  ],
)
```

From the [Expanded-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) documentation:

> A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the
>   child fills the available space.